# Using tsconfig paths with Angular libraries?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating an Angular library and within `tsconfig.lib.json` I've added the following `paths` configuration:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@fs/*": ["src/lib/*"]
    }        
  }
```

However attempting to import things like:

```
import { Test } from '@fs/Test'
```

Does not work.  Anyone know if Angular libraries support hte `paths` configuration option within `tsconfig.lib.json`?

Generally I use `typescript-transform-paths` to perform path transformation on the compiled result, and I was hoping Angular had baked something like this in for libraries?

Comment: It's a long shot but sometimes you have to reopen vscode and restart server for the new paths to be recognized. Try this if you haven't already.

Comment: In this case it's not recognizing it in the tooling.  It will recognize it for normal Angular application projects, but it's not working in the library project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following pattern in your **tsconfig.json** file :

```
"paths": {
  "@services/*": ["app/path/to/services/*"],
  "@components/*": ["app/path/to/some/deeply/nested/component/*"],
  "@environments/*": ["environments/*"] 
},
```

Then when importing:

```
import { yourServiceClass } from "@services/yourServiceClass";
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works - I had to add it to the top level `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: This is my Jest configuration in case someone is trying to do something similar: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/unit-testing-your-angular-library-project-with-jest-42429a8716eb

Comment: What am I missing, this looks exactly the same as the question. Is the only difference that it's at the top level and not in compilerOptions? If so, please put that in the answer